# How to calculate the longest period in days that a company has gone without headcount change?

Tags: sql, oracle

Given an employees table with the columns EmpID,FirstName,LastName,StartDate, and EndDate.
I want to use a query on Oracle to calculate the longest period in days that a company has gone without headcount change.

Here is my query:

```
select MAX(endDate-startDate)

from
(select endDate 
from employees
where endDate is not null)

union all 

(select startDate 
from employees)
```

But I got an error:
ORA-00904:"STARTDATE":invalid identifier

***How can I fix this error? 
Is my query the correct answer to this question?***

Thanks

Comment: Regardless of any syntax errors, `enddate - startdate` will calculate how long an employee has been with the company (and then you take max over that, so you take the longest time someone has been with the firm). It is hard to see how that has anything to do with knowing the longest time the company did not have a change in headcount. So, it is not worth trying to fix what you have, since it will calculate the wrong thing anyway.

Comment: @Judy . . . You should clarify what a change in headcount really means by including sample data and desired results, with particular attention on cases where an employees start and leave on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning the startDate in the sub-query. Add startDate to the inner query.

```
select MAX(endDate-startDate) from 
(select startDate, endDate from employees where endDate is not null) 
union all
(select startDate from employees)
```

EDIT:

You can also try this:

```
select MAX(endDate-startDate) from employees where endDate is not null
```

However, I don't think your query is what you're looking for as it only lists the longest term employee that no longer works at the company.

Answer (score 1):

In a simplistic view, you would want to put together all the start-dates (when the headcount increases) and all the end-dates (when it decreases), combine them all, arrange them in increasing order, measure the differences between consecutive dates, and take the max.

"Put together" is a `UNION ALL`, and measure differences between "consecutive" dates can be done with the analytic function `lag()`.

One complication: one employee may start exactly on the same date another is terminated, so the headcount doesn't change. More generally, on any given date there may be starts and ends, and you need to exclude the dates when there are an equal number of starts and ends. So the first part of the solution is more complicated: you need to group by date and compare the start and end counts.

Something like this may work (not tested!):

```
with d ( dt, flag ) as (
       select start_date, 's' from employees union all
       select end_date  , 'e' from employees
     ),
     prep ( int ) as 
       select   dt - lag(dt) over (order by dt)
       from     d
       group by dt
       having   count(case flag when 's' then 1 end) != 
                                              count(case flag when 'e' then 1 end)
     )
select max(int) as max_interval
from   prep
;
```

**Edit** - Gordon has a good point in his solution: perhaps the longest period without a change in headcount is the current period (ending "now"). For this reason, one needs to add SYSDATE to the UNION ALL, like he did. It can be added with either flag (for example 's' to be specific).

Comment: so if someone enter and other person quit the same day, you take it as headcount didnt change?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - Yes. Same if eight people started and eight left on the same day. I explained this in the text before the code.

Comment: Yes, I read and was checking if understand right. I was doing the same, but in my case if eight ppl start and eight left I consider 16 headcount changes  on that day, each with length `0 days`. Just different interpratation of the problem ;)

Comment: btw is easy to change between both version, just change `UNION ALL` for `UNION`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I ran a small company before I retired (with other partners) and "headcount" and "headcount changes" were meant the way I used here. Replacing one employee with another on the same day does not change the headcount.

Comment: With the other interpretation, it's easier - I can keep UNION ALL (duplicates cause intervals of zero days, which don't change the MAX, and UNION is expensive) and I don't need GROUP BY.

Comment: current date is easy to fix changing lag to `lead(dt,1,CURRENT_DATE))`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - you are right, that's much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is something like this:

```
select max(span)
from (select (lead(dte) over (order by dte) - dte) as span
      from (select startDate as dte from employees union all
            select endDate as dte from employees union all
            select trunc(sysdate) from dual
           ) d
     ) d;
```

A head-count change (presumably) occurs when an employee starts or stops.  Hence, you want the largest interval between two such adjacent dates.

Comment: Having been involved in HR (running a small business), I happen to know that "change in head count" really means change. When one employee leaves on the same day another starts, that is NOT considered a change in headcount. So the solution needs to be more complicated than that. (Otherwise you just coded what I explained in the first two paragraphs in my Answer.)

Comment: @mathguy . . . The OP would need to clarify exactly what a change in headcount really entails.

Comment: Thanks. 
select max(span)
from (select (lead(dte) over (order by dte) - dte) as span
      from (select startDate as dte from employees union all
            select endDate as dte from employees union all
            select trunc(sysdate) from dual
           ) d
     ) d;
is the correct answer.